# IOS and Android with C# webservices

Tags: c#, android, ios, iphone, web-services

****Hello All Expert Programmers, I need your help for writing c# webservices,****

1- I know how to create post and get request in C# and how to consume it with android or ios already test on loacal host, but iam not aware of method for file uploading, so how to create a method in c# webservice that receive an image.

2- How to request from IOS and Android its like simple Post request or Multipart request?

3- How to deploy the webservice to live server, currently it is on local iis server with SQL Database.

Bundle of thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of tutorials and resources for this stuff.

Comment: Nasch i try my best but i cant get the exact thing that i mention in the question.

Comment: I didn't mean how hard have you tried. Post your code and explain what's going wrong. That's how this site works. If you want general advice try programmers exchange.

Comment: Well you read my question again.

Comment: I read it again.  You still didn't post any code.

Comment: nasch if you read and understand my question than tell me if i have code than why i ask such questions? i dont want to fix code part i need whole code or helping sites that contain data about file upload using wcf from android and ios client. Thanks

Comment: OK I think you're on the wrong site then.  You should do an internet search for tutorials on the subjects you need help with, or look for a site where you can hire a programmer to do the work.